# Can I Change Caps Lock to Hyper/Additional Modifier?

Tags: keyboard-layout, emacs, xkb

In Arch Linux, I have Caps Lock function as an alternate Ctrl: In the console through a personal keymap, and in X through a "kbd" option in `xorg.conf`.

I've already researched a little about changing Caps Lock to a Hyper modifier, and it sounded like this wasn't feasible in the console,  but is there any way I can do this for X?

Here's what I currently use for X:

```
Option "XkbOptions" "ctrl:nocaps"
```

Is there an `XkbOptions` option or something similar to make Caps Lock act like an additional modifier?

My goal in this is to be able to create more custom keymappings in Emacs with the new modifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the other answers using xmodmap are correct, there is a far easier way. Instead of:

```
Option "XkbOptions" "ctrl:nocaps"
```

Just use:

```
Option "XkbOptions" "caps:hyper"
```

You can find all the options in /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/base.lst

Comment: For me this assigned caps to super key, not hyper key.

Answer (score 8):

This may be easier to do with xmodmap. Put the following into your .xsession or .xinitrc:

```
xmodmap -e "keysym Caps_Lock = Hyper_L"
```

You will also need to make sure Hyper_L is assigned to a modifier map not shared with other keys, otherwise it may generate the modifier for those keys instead (or those keys may become Hyper). Run `xmodmap` with not parameters (your output may differ):

```
> xmodmap
xmodmap:  up to 3 keys per modifier, (keycodes in parentheses):

shift       Shift_L (0x32),  Shift_R (0x3e)
lock      
control     Control_L (0x25),  Control_L (0x42),  Control_R (0x69)
mod1        Alt_L (0x40),  Alt_R (0x6c),  Meta_L (0xcd)
mod2        Num_Lock (0x4d)
mod3        
mod4        Super_L (0x85),  Super_R (0x86),  Super_L (0xce), Hyper_L (0x4e)
mod5        ISO_Level3_Shift (0x5c),  Mode_switch (0xcb)
```

In this example, Hyper_L is assigned to the same modifer as the Super keys, and so is treated as a Super key. These commands will remove it from mod4 and put it into the empty mod3 modifier map:

```
xmodmap -e "remove Mod4 = Hyper_L" -e "add Mod3 = Hyper_L"
```

If Hyper_L doesn't appear in the modifier map listing, the remove command may not be necessary.

The modifier map arcanity is due to how X11 communicates whether a modifier is down. It sends a one-byte bitfield, each bit corresponding to one of the modifier maps, rather than sending "Hyper" or "Super". Applications have to go and look at the modifier map and figure out what a particular bit actually meant. If you have e.g. both Super and Hyper keys assigned to mod4, an application has no way to tell if Super or Hyper (or both) is being held down.

Comment: It works (`xev` picks up CapsLock as Hyper_L)...but its acting more like Shift than Ctrl/Alt, and Emacs doesn't pick it up as a modifier.  Is there something additional I can do?

Comment: @mellowmaroon I expanded my answer, it should now have what you need to get it working. I'm guessing an `xmodmap -e "remove shift = Hyper_L" -e "add mod3 = Hyper_L"` may be what it needs, or maybe `mod1` or `mod4` instead of `shift`.

Comment: I tried moving Hyper into Mod3 like you have, but it's still doing the same thing.  I really appreciate the assistance though.  Anything else that might be messing it up?

Comment: @mellowmaroon This answer should have everything you need. Maybe your initial modifier configuration is different from wingedsubmariner's and so you need to change it differently. Post the output of `xmodmap`.

Comment: Ok I have everything working now!  It turned out to be the console Emacs' inability to detect Super and Hyper (at least with `urxvt`) that was throwing me off.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
keycode 66 = BackSpace
remove Mod4 = Hyper_L
add Mod3 = Hyper_L
keycode 66 = Hyper_L
```